# how to change the icons dynamically into a styled-component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am new to styled-component and I am getting an error stating :

Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'ThemeProps'.

I want to give an icon in props. For one icon it works. I don't know how to do it so that I can change it many times.

```
export const GenericInput = styled.input`
background-color: #f4f4f4;
width: 220px;
height: 47px;
border: none;
border-radius: 50px;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
letter-spacing: 1px;
padding: 15px 30px;
-moz-outline-radius: 50px;    
outline: none;

     ${(Icon) => 
    Icon && css`
        background-image: url(${({ icon }) => icon});
        background-size: 20px;
        background-position: 10px 50%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        color: #c7c7c7;
    `
} 

::placeholder {
    color: #c7c7c7;
}
`;
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876313/pass-background-url-as-prop-to-styled-component) solve your problem?

Comment: If I add <any> to GenericInput and move 'background' higher then it works.

`export const GenericInput = styled.input`
background-image: ${props => `url(${props.background})`}; 
`;`

but i dont know how add <any> in Icon

Comment: It works as it should :) thanks